# How to disable chat history in Mozilla Thunderbird?

Tags: logging, chat, history, thunderbird

Chat is a wonderful feature in Mozilla Thunderbird. But where is the option for removing chat history?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that it's a proven bug in Mozilla Thunderbird 38.2.0:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=788145

So there would be a patch later from Mozilla and this is a temporary workaround. Now back to the hack:

1- Press Alt and go to the Tools > Options > Advanced > General

2- Click "Config Editor" button then click ***I'll be careful, I promise!*** to proceed.

3- Set the values of these keys to **false**:

```
purple.logging.log_chats

purple.logging.log_ims

purple.logging.log_system
```

4- Close the Config Editor and Options window

5- Browse to the path below and remove all the folders except .system

```
C:\Users\YOUR_WINDOWS_USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\SOME_HASH_CODE.default\logs\YOUR_CHAT_PROVIDER\YOUR_CHAT_ACCOUNT
```

6- Now remove your chat account from Mozilla Thunderbird and add it again.

7- Everything should be OK now.